# Quartz not firing simple trigger

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler

This should be pretty straight forward, but I see no job being executed. I have a breakpoint on the execute() method of the task, no thread gets there ever.
I'm not getting what's wrong.

the Job

```
class Printer implements Job{
    public Printer(){
        System.out.println("created printer");
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context)
            throws JobExecutionException {
        System.out.println("hi" + context.getFireTime());
    }

}
```

The main class

```
class MyClass {
      public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
            Scheduler s = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();
            JobDetail job = newJob(Printer.class).build();
            CronTrigger trigger = 
                    newTrigger()
                    .withIdentity("a", "t")
                    .withSchedule(cronSchedule("0/5 * * * * ?").inTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault()))
                    .forJob(job).build();
            s.scheduleJob(job, trigger);

// This prints the right date!

            System.out.println(trigger.getNextFireTime()); 
            s.start();
        }
}
```

**EDIT**: I discovered I didn't have the quartz.property file, so there was the possibility the threadpool for quartz was not ever created. Therefore as read in [documentation](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.0/org/quartz/impl/DirectSchedulerFactory.html), I replaced the code using StdSchedulerFactory with the following:

```
DirectSchedulerFactory.getInstance().createVolatileScheduler(10);
Scheduler s = DirectSchedulerFactory.getInstance().getScheduler();
```

Guess what? No luck still. Same identical effect. Application keeps staying alive, firing not trigger.

Comment: Doesn't your program just terminate?

Comment: No because I don't shutdown the scheduler (in purpose).

Comment: Did you actually confirm that your application does not simply end just after `s.start()`?

Comment: I confirm it stays alive. It terminates immediately if I put s.shutdown() as last instruction. Previous version of my test program included a sleep of ten minutes and then the s.shutdown(). The effect was that the process terminated after 10m. But for the sake of simplicity I published the one without. I tested either ways. I imagined this was the intended behaviour.

Comment: Btw, for anyone reading this, Quartz loads up default properties even when you do not provide the quartz.properties file. Check out the documentation [here](https://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/configuration/#:~:text=By%20default%2C%20StdSchedulerFactory%20load%20a,org%2Fquartz%20package%20is%20loaded.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found the solution: changing the visibility of the class defining the job (Printer) to **public** will make it possible to Quartz to access it and run it.

```
public class Printer implements Job { // just add 'public'!
    public Printer() {
        System.out.println("created printer");
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context)
            throws JobExecutionException {
        System.out.println("hi" + context.getFireTime());
    }

}
```

That's understandable, since it's only possible to pass a `<? extends Job>.class`
to the scheduler (bloody hell, why??) and not - for example - anonymous objects.

Having that said, **I find really upsetting the way Quartz silently fails firing jobs without a single error message.**

Comment: Another problem may be if the constractor require parameters or not public. I found my problem thanks to you.

Comment: I had the same issue.  I also find it very odd/frustrating that no error messages are given at all...

Comment: You made my day!

Comment: Did you ever discover why Quartz silently failed firing jobs? I am facing the same issue and cannot explain why since it works the vast majority of the time.

Comment: From the v2.3.0 [documentation](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-03.html):
"...jobs must have a no-argument constructor (when using the default JobFactory implementation)"

Answer (score 0):

What fixed the issue for me was making the Job class **static**, including **the objects the Job uses**. In my case I was making a Discord bot and wanted to present some news every day at X time.

```
public class BotListeners extends ListenerAdapter {

private JDA jda = null;
private static TextChannel generalChannel;
private static TextChannel newsChannel;
private static UoiScraper scraper;

/* Other methods we dont care about */



public static class NewsJob implements Job{
    public NewsJob(){
        System.out.println("Creating job");
    }
    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) throws JobExecutionException{
        newsChannel.getIterableHistory().forEach(message -> message.delete().queue());
        scraper.presentNewsForDiscord(newsChannel);
    }
}

public void sendDailyNews() throws SchedulerException {
    Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
    scheduler.start();

    JobDetail scrapeNewsJob = JobBuilder.newJob(NewsJob.class)
            .withIdentity("presentNewsForDiscordJob", "group1")
            .build();

    //trigger every day at 12:58
    Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
            .withIdentity("presentNewsForDiscordTrigger", "group1")
            .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 55 4 * * ?"))
            .build();
    System.out.println("News will be renewed in " + trigger.getStartTime());

    scheduler.scheduleJob(scrapeNewsJob, trigger);
}
```